# sencha touch store load data from json but when accessing the view the store item is empty

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I am having some issue with sencha touch data store. I am loading the data from jsonp to a store. The data is getting stored correctly. but when i access the view immediately with the store value and the object is empty.

I am not sure why?

data store :

```
parking.stores.ParkingFacility = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'PF',
    autoLoad: true
});

var GetData = function (lat, long) {
    Ext.util.JSONP.request({
        url: 'http://stg-parking.511.org/index/M_GetParkingFacilitiesByLatLng',
        callbackKey: 'callback',
        params: { latitude: lat, longitude: long },
        callback: function (data) {
            var result = data.Root;
            parking.stores.ParkingFacility.loadData(data.Root);
            parking.stores.ParkingFacility.save();
        }

    });


};
```

The GetData function populates the store with the json value.

View:

```
parking.views.mapComponent = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    title: 'Map',
    mapOptions: {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.381592, -122.135672),
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        render: function (comp, map) {

            var pdata = parking.stores.ParkingFacility;

        }
    }

});
```

The pdata value in the listener is empty.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards, 
Pawan

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not loading the data until the view gets rendered. Due to the asynchronous nature of Javascript, it's no surprise that the view doesn't reflect the data in the store.

I'd looking into ways that work with the async situation. For example, make the component listen to store's `datachanged` event and rerender itself accordingly, or do this in a controller.

Comment: Thanks danmarner for the help. Can you show me a snippet for making the component listen to store's datachanged event and rerender itself accordingly. I am totally new to sencha touch.

Comment: i have updated my controller to something like this store.on('dataChanged', function() {   parking.views.viewport.setActiveItem(
                parking.views.map, options.animation
            );
        });  The view render method is never called. Can you tell me what could be the problem. Is it necessary to remove and add the component for it to render properly or how can i forcefully call the render method.

Comment: The event name is all lowercase. Aka `datachanged` instead of `dataChanged`